# POST zip file to ArcGIS Server using an API (Python)

Tags: arcgis-server, api, arcgis-enterprise, enterprise, flask

I have built an API in python using the Flask framework. My goal is to be able to upload files from a local directory (in this case E:) into ArcGIS Enterprise Server. From there the service can be viewed in ArcGIS Enterprise Portal. Below is my current script and the error message I am recieving. It looks like there is something off in my script and/or I haven't defined the ArcGIS Enterprise Server endpoint correctly. How can I this script, so that I can upload a single item (in this case a zip file) onto ArcGIS Enterprise Server?

```
    #import modules
    import requests
    import os
    from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template, flash
    from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename


try:
# bypass SSL certificate
requests.post(url='https://domain/server/rest/services/', data={'bar':'baz'}, verify=False)

try:

    #set local variables
    service = 'https://domain/server/rest/services/'
    #upload folder contains one zip file that has a shapefile
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = r'E:\API_creation\upload'
    ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'zip'}

    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    path = UPLOAD_FOLDER
    
    if not os.path.isdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
        os.mkdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
    
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
    
    def allowed_file(filename):
        return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
    
    
    @app.route('/')
    def upload_form():
        return render_template(service)
    
    
    @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
    def upload_file():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # check if the post request has the file part
            if 'file' not in request.files:
                flash('No file part')
                return redirect(request.url)
            file = request.files['file']
            if file.filename == '':
                flash('No file selected for uploading')
                return redirect(request.url)
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                flash('File successfully uploaded')
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                flash('Allowed file types are txt, pdf, png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
                return redirect(request.url)
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host = "https://domain/server/rest/services/", port = 6443, debug = False)
        
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Didn't work this time.")
```

Here is the error message that I am getting:

- Serving Flask app "appName" (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: off
  [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: `getaddrinfo failed` typically means that the server can't be reached. I'm assuming you masked the server information in your above code snippet and you are not trying to reach `https://domain` ?

Comment: Yeah I masked it for the post. It goes directly to the domain name though.

Comment: Is 'server' the name of your web adaptor? Typically the default is 'arcgis' but can be changed.